# cifs mount statement from bash script fails and only returns usage suggestions

Tags: bash, mount, cifs

Background:
I have two raspberry pi's running ubuntu Mate and I have a bash script that runs a mount command on both.

Raspberry Pi1 is working fine but when I copied over the files for pi2, I cannot connect for some reason.

my bash script looks like this...

```
#!/bin/bash
# Mount Shared Folder on Jay's computer
jip=$(php /var/www/html/Update-Project-Files/utilities/get_jay_ip_for_pi2.php)
echo $jip
mount -t cifs -o username=username,password=pass,uid=33 '//'$jip/work_video_files /var/www/html/Update-Project-Files/Mounts/Jay_mount
```

This calls a php file to get the ip for the shared folder computer and then calls the mount.  I have changed nothing because it works fine on my first machine but for some reason it will not work for the 2nd machine.

if I try the command from the commandline and sub in the IP I am able to mount the folder successfully but running this script from the commandline will only print the IP from the echo(as expected) and then the usage for mount is displayed.. I guess telling me my mount command is wrong?

so output looks like:

```
pi2@pi2:~$ sudo /bin/bash /var/www/html/Update-Project-Files/scripts/mount_shared_folder_for_pi2.sh 2>&1
```

xxx.xxx.xxx.xx

Usage:
 mount [-lhV]
 mount -a [options]
 mount [options] [--source]  | [--target] 
 mount [options]  
 mount   []

Mount a filesystem.

Options:
 -a, --all               mount all filesystems mentioned in fstab
 -c, --no-canonicalize   don't canonicalize paths
 -f, --fake              dry run; skip the mount(2) syscall
 -F, --fork              fork off for each device (use with -a)
 -T, --fstab       alternative file to /etc/fstab
 -i, --internal-only     don't call the mount. helpers
 -l, --show-labels       show also filesystem labels
 -n, --no-mtab           don't write to /etc/mtab
 -o, --options     comma-separated list of mount options
 -O, --test-opts   limit the set of filesystems (use with -a)
 -r, --read-only         mount the filesystem read-only (same as -o ro)
 -t, --types       limit the set of filesystem types
     --source       explicitly specifies source (path, label, uuid)
     --target    explicitly specifies mountpoint
 -v, --verbose           say what is being done
 -w, --rw, --read-write  mount the filesystem read-write (default)

-h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

Source:
 -L, --label      synonym for LABEL=
 -U, --uuid        synonym for UUID=
 LABEL=           specifies device by filesystem label
 UUID=             specifies device by filesystem UUID
 PARTLABEL=       specifies device by partition label
 PARTUUID=         specifies device by partition UUID
                 specifies device by path
              mountpoint for bind mounts (see --bind/rbind)
                   regular file for loopdev setup

Operations:
 -B, --bind              mount a subtree somewhere else (same as -o bind)
 -M, --move              move a subtree to some other place
 -R, --rbind             mount a subtree and all submounts somewhere else
 --make-shared           mark a subtree as shared
 --make-slave            mark a subtree as slave
 --make-private          mark a subtree as private
 --make-unbindable       mark a subtree as unbindable
 --make-rshared          recursively mark a whole subtree as shared
 --make-rslave           recursively mark a whole subtree as slave
 --make-rprivate         recursively mark a whole subtree as private
 --make-runbindable      recursively mark a whole subtree as unbindable

Any thoughts on why or what further steps I could take to pinpoint the issue?

After further thinking... I believe this is because pi1 has an entry for the mount in fstab but pi2 does not.  I will need to check tomorrow when I get to that machine.  I was unaware that mounts necessarily needed an entry in fstab.  I thought fstab ran scripts at startup but from reading this...

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

I feel I did not understand fstab before.  Does this sound feasible?

Final Update....
I was never able to get this working and to boot had ethernet connection issues so I just scrapped it.  I am focused elsewhere now.  I am new to linux but am finding out that so many errors seem to be underlying permissions problems perhaps the mounting error above was the same.

Comment: I'd start by checking *exactly* what's returned from your php command - make sure it doesn't have trailing whitespace or non-printable characters (such as a carriage return)

Comment: So, based on your "final update" you are no longer interested in an answer to this question?

Comment: @OrganicMarble correct!